# Matplotlib: cbar.set_xticklabels has no effects

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've assigned the 365 days of a year to several clusters and I'm now trying to plot them on a heatmap.

My code works fine except that cbar.set_ticks(some_range) has no effects: the tick labels on my colorbar have the right text but the wrong position [image: a colorbar with wrong yticks]

Here is a MCVE

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

#create some random data
n_cluster = 4
index = pd.date_range('01/01/2016', end='31/12/2016', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, n_cluster, len(index)), 
             index=index, columns=['cluster'])

pivot = df.pivot_table('cluster', 
    columns=[lambda x: x.weekofyear], 
    index= [lambda x: x.dayofweek])

#yticklabels of the heatmap
days =  [date(2018, 1, d).strftime('%a')[:3] for d in range(1, 8)]

#get a discrete cmap
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu', n_cluster)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[50,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
cbar = plt.subplot(gs[1])
sns.heatmap(pivot, square=True, cmap=cmap,
            yticklabels=days, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar)

#There is something wrong here
cbar.set_yticks([i + 1/(2.0*n_cluster) for i in np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/n_cluster)])

#This one is ok
cbar.set_yticklabels(range(0, n_cluster))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where do you want the tick labels to be?

Comment: I'd like them to be aligned with the color patches, e.g "3" standing at the middle of the dark blue patch. Respectively at `[0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875]` of the total height of the color bar.

Comment: Looks like seaborn somehow enforces the tick positions. In the future it will be perhaps be possible to set the colorbar ticks in the `cbar_kws` argument, but this is currently broken for `'ticks'` ([see here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/459)).

Comment: Uh, I just realized that issue is almost a year old. maybe it will not make it into seaborn after all... Anyway, This doesn't help now and I don't know a workaround. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, the following adds the correct labels in the correct place,

```
cbar.yaxis.set_ticks([0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875])
```

which looks like,
[image]

EDIT:
Or the more general suggestion of mfitzp,

```
cbar.yaxis.set_ticks([i + 1/(2.0*n_cluster) 
                      for i in np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/n_cluster)])
```

Comment: To give a complete answer you could use `cbar.yaxis.set_ticks([i + 1/(2.0*n_cluster) for i in np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/n_cluster)])`